# Picasso takes too much time to load image in real device compared to emulator

Tags: android, performance, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images in app where it takes to much time to load in real device compared to android emulator.

In emulator it hardly takes 10 to 15 seconds were in real device it takes minimum of 5 to 7 minutes

Real devices used to test this :

- Mi Note 3
- Mi Note 4
- Mi A1
- Oppo F1

I am using free server and here is the configuration :

- OS : Windows 7
- Ram : 1GB
- Storage : 10Gb

Images are displayed in image view and called from adapters.

- Images count : ~300
- Size : ~1.5 to 3 mb

Here is the code to load image :

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(path)
       .skipMemoryCache()
       .resize(300, 300)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
       .into(view);
```

Comment: `using free server` The same for emulator and device?

Comment: `it hardly takes 10 to 15 seconds`. How do you test? Scrolling a listview or something like that?

Comment: is your PC connected to LAN network? because emulator uses the LAN internet and real devices use the network providers internet. so LAN internet is always fast as compared to network providers internet

Comment: Yes I am using same free server for emulator and time is approximate.

Comment: @HiteshSarsava, laptop and real device is connected to same wifi network

Comment: then it should not be problem @VinitShah with loading image by Picasso

Answer (score 0):

Use `Glide` instead of `Picasso`
It will load images faster

Go through this link https://github.com/bumptech/glide and add `Glide` in your Gradle

Add the below code where you want to load image like

```
Glide.with(context)
   .load(path)
   .into(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the images on the server you should compress them (services like tinypng.com can reduce file sizes by >80% in most cases) as the real issue here seems to be the time taken to download the images as opposed to Picasso

Comment: `as opposed to Picasso` ? Dont understand. Picasso is used both on emulator and device.

Comment: I'm saying Picasso is not the reason for the time taken to load the images. 1.5 - 3 mb images and the time taken to download them is going to have a bigger impact.

Comment: I still do not understand why you even named Picasso.

Comment: Check the question title

Comment: Not a good reason to name Picasso as you cannot blame Picasso.  But you may be right that it is a download time issue.

Comment: Developer cites Picasso as the reason for the download taking time. Not a good reason to name Picasso? ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide it's better than picaso